# Unexpected output when printing enum values

Tags: c#, enums

I have some code that takes a `ulong` parameter, and by using a mapping dictionary, maps that ulong to a value in an `enum`. However, the enum contains values that are the same for all intents an purposes, so those are re-assigned later on in the enum in a similar fashion as `AfricanMango` is in the following enum:

```
public enum Fruits
{
    Banana = 0,
    Strawberry,
    Apple,
    Peach,
    Mango,
    Berry,

    AfricanMango = Mango,

    Cranberry
}
```

This *should* tell the compiler to use the same values for both `AfricanMango` and `Mango`, whether this implementation actually makes sense from a design point of view is up in the air.

My code was converting the input to an enum value just fine, and when evaluating the result of the function, it returned `Fruits.Cranberry`. This was the value I was expecting.

However, when subsequently using the result of that function (which the debugger *claimed* was `Fruits.Cranberry`), the result suddenly shifted to `Fruits.Berry`, as can be demonstrated by running the below code:

```
var fruit = Fruits.Cranberry;

Console.WriteLine(fruit);
```

One would expect this to output `Cranberry`, as that is the value it was assigned, but in reality this outputs `Berry`.

Is this intended behaviour? Do enums get looked up based on the value before them, and is the assignment of `AfricanMango` messing that up somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't specify a value for your `enum` items, they are created sequentially. So in this case `AfricanMango` has a value equivalent to `Mango` which means the values after will be `Mango + 1` which maps to `Berry`.

From the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx):

> By default, the first enumerator has the value 0, and the value of each successive enumerator is increased by 1

Comment: Ugh, I love "we hate you" features >.< That calls for compiler warning.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the assignment is just incremented. It indeed takes the value of the previous item + 1. See the code from Reflector:

```
public enum Fruits
{
    AfricanMango = 4,
    Apple = 2,
    Banana = 0,
    Berry = 5,
    Cranberry = 5, // <-- uch
    Mango = 4,
    Peach = 3,
    Strawberry = 1
}
```

You should put calculated values in the end. In that way the counting won't break, or assign values manually.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx):

> By default, the first enumerator has the value 0, and the value of each successive enumerator is increased by 1. For example, in the following enumeration, Sat is 0, Sun is 1, Mon is 2, and so forth.